# Mail Composition Interface Doesn't Appear?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to replicates Apple "Sending a Mail Message" code, but the email composition interface doen't appear.. just a blank screen.  I think I did this right.  Didn't do anything with the storyboard since there aren't any actions or outlets.  Didn't change either of the delegate .h or .m files.  Below is the code.  Very new to coding.  What have I missed?

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Hello from New Zealand!"];

    // Set up the recipients.
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jfellows123@gmail.com",
                             nil];
    NSArray *ccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jfellows123@gmail.com", nil];
    NSArray *bccRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"jfellows123@gmail.com",
                              nil];

    [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];
    [picker setCcRecipients:ccRecipients];
    [picker setBccRecipients:bccRecipients];

    // Attach an image to the email.
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"IMG_3639"
                                                     ofType:@"jpg"];
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/jpg"
                     fileName:@"IMG_3639"];

    // Fill out the email body text.
    NSString *emailBody = @"Beautiful New Zealand!";
    [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    // Present the mail composition interface.
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// The mail compose view controller delegate method
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller
          didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result
                        error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: where do u call this `displayComposerSheet`?

Comment: u need to call your method to show the mailcomposer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind . Where you are calling the `-(void)displayComposerSheet` method. ?

It doesn't get called right . If so Let me know your log . Use breakPoints .

Comment: I think I was just too tired last night.  I put in an IBAction for displayComposerSheet and it worked fine.  Thanks.